# PHP find similar array keys and sum of the values

Tags: php, csv, foreach

I have a csv file and it has four fields which are time,sip,dip and data.

I need to find all sips which starts with "10." and if sips are same add all data field and display the value with sip.

I have tried the code below. But how can I search the array to check whether sips are same, if they are same add all data field.

```
$lines =file('/files/cjsv.csv');
$records=array();
foreach($lines as $data)
{
  list($time,$sip,$dip,$data)= explode(',',$data);
  if(substr($sip, 0, 3 )=="10.")
  {
     echo $sip."=".$data."<br/>";
     $records[$sip]=$data;
  }

}
var_dump($records);
```

Example of a csv file:

```
2014-10-31 23:34:24,17.172.208.49,10.101.224.170,500
2014-10-31 23:34:16,178.206.115.117,10.101.224.170,400
2014-10-31 23:34:23,10.101.16.218,17.167.138.38,200
2014-10-31 23:34:23,10.101.16.218,17.167.138.38,100
2014-10-31 23:34:24,54.249.250.113,10.101.13.22,80
2014-10-31 23:34:24,17.167.140.109,10.101.1.1,80
2014-10-31 23:34:24,134.170.188.84,10.101.1.1,80
2014-10-31 23:34:23,10.101.16.219,17.167.138.38,50
```

Expected output is:

10.101.16.218=300(200+100)

10.101.16.219=50

Comment: actually which part is not working...?? I know your answer...

Comment: Could you post a result? So the output you are expecting..

Comment: I have updated the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this code and it's outputting the result that you want...

```
$lines =file('/files/cjsv.csv');
$records=array();
foreach($lines as $data)
{
  list($time,$sip,$dip,$data)= explode(',',$data);
  if(substr($sip, 0, 3 )=="10.")
  {
     //echo $sip."=".$data."<br/>";
     $records[$sip] += $data;          // changed this
  }
}
var_dump($records);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["10.101.16.218"]=>
  int(300)
  ["10.101.16.219"]=>
  int(50)
}
```

I changed only one command from your solution `"$records[$sip]=$data;"` to `"$records[$sip] += $data;"`... `"="` will replace the previous value you recorded where `"+="` will increment the value, that you want...

feel free to ask if you have any further questions...

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
if(key_exists($sip, $records){
    $records[$sip] += $data;
} else {
    $records[$sip] = $data;
}
```

Comment: maybe you were referring to `array_key_exists`, or just use isset

Comment: `key_exists()` is simply an alias of `array_key_exists()`

Comment: actually whats unclear is that whether the OP need to need another set of array inside the container to just add sum those last digits